# what do these statements mean and is this style recommended ?

Tags: java, static-import

Recently i cam across a statements :

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.exit;
```

I read these statements in some tutorial. Are these statements O.K ?

If the statements are alright what do they mean and *should they be used regularly while writing code ?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called *static imports*. The effect is to allow you to use the names `out` and `exit` in your program as if they were defined in the current scope; so you can write `exit(0)` instead of `System.exit(0)`.

Now, are they a good idea? Sometimes, when used sparingly, they are a good way to reduce clutter. But most of the time, they actually just make your code harder to understand. The reader will ask "Where is this `out` defined?" and "Where does `exit()` come from?" In general, you should avoid them.

But if you're writing a class that's all about processing `SomeReallyLongName` objects, and `SomeReallyLongName` defines a bunch of `FINAL_CONSTANTS`, importing them with static imports will save a lot of typing and a lot of clutter, and it will be pretty clear where those constants are coming from.

Answer (score 3):

They are static imports. It allows you to do something like `exit(0)` instead of `System.exit(0)`.

I do not recommend this for well known Java classes because it can be confusing to some. But sometimes it is useful for utility classes like [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

```
Iterables.filter(list, SomeClass.class)
```

is very verbose but you can make it easier to read with static imports: `filter(list, SomeClass.class)`

You should check with your team to see what they code guidelines are and try to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it is perfectly alright .

This is known as `static import`.This allows members defined in class as `static` and
`public` to be used without specifying the class in which the field is defined.
This feature was defined in `J2SE 5.0`.
For example :

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import static java.lang.System.out; 
// in main
out.print( max(100,200) ); // prints 200.You didn't have to use Math.max(.,.)
```

I think it may not be a good idea to use static imports as it'll make your code hard to read.

Comment: You say its perfectly alright but then you say it might not be a good idea. :) I think that sound confusing.

Comment: @ Amir Raminfar At one point of question it is asked **Are these statements OK** ,  so i said yes it is perfectly alright. It may not be a good idea using these imports but they are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these statements are referred to as `static imports` and are perfectly valid. Take a look at the [javase guide on static imports](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) for more information.

With respect to usage, the guide states:

> So when should you use static import? Very sparingly! Only use it when
>   you'd otherwise be tempted to declare local copies of constants, or to
>   abuse inheritance (the Constant Interface Antipattern). In other
>   words, use it when you require frequent access to static members from
>   one or two classes. If you overuse the static import feature, it can
>   make your program unreadable and unmaintainable, polluting its
>   namespace with all the static members you import. Readers of your code
>   (including you, a few months after you wrote it) will not know which
>   class a static member comes from. Importing all of the static members
>   from a class can be particularly harmful to readability; if you need
>   only one or two members, import them individually. Used appropriately,
>   static import can make your program more readable, by removing the
>   boilerplate of repetition of class names.

Answer (score 0):

[Static imports are a new feature added in Java 1.5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

> The static import construct allows unqualified access to static members without inheriting from the type containing the static members. Instead, the program imports the members, either individually

There is nothing wrong with your example if you want easy access to `out` and `exit` so that you can call them directly as `out.println()` for example. There is nothing syntactically incorrect about it nor from a style aspect though some may argue it is "confusing" and hard to figure out where `out` came from, but any modern IDE can help them figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

These are static import concept.These are like simple imports but having different type of concept.See here you import one function **exit()** and one field **out** and both are static  in their corresponding classes(in case both here Systen is their class).After this instead of writing **System.out.println()** you can simply write **out.println()**.Similarly instead of **System.exit()**,you can write **exit()**.